# pointer being freed was not allocated after removing a string

Tags: c++, netbeans-7

I'm trying to remove a specific word from a text file and then rewrite the remaining values into a new file. I believe that the error arises from the code here:

```
string removeWord(string r){
    ifstream wordBase("WordDatabase.txt");
    ofstream temp("temp.txt");

    string line = "";
    while(getline(wordBase,line))
    {
        if(line != r)
            temp << line << endl;
    }

    temp.close();
    wordBase.close();
    remove("WordDatabase.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","WordDatabase.txt");
}
```

Can someon help me out here? Highly appreciated!

Comment: You have declared the function return type as string yet you do not return a string from your function.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting exactly ? (Plus as @JohnSheridan pointed out, you're missing a return statement or you declared the wrong return type).

Comment: Can you post the code for remove() and rename() methods? That would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks John. That was a stupid mistake. Only been doing c++ for a week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has undefined behaviour as (pointed out by [John Sheridan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423491/john-sheridan)) the function `removeWord()` is not `return`ing a `string` *but* a `string` as its return type. From section *6.6.3 The return statement* of the c++11 standard (draft n3337), clause 2:

> ...Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

It is pointless trying to reason about the behaviour of a program that has undefined behaviour but given there is an error in the code related to a `string` and `string` is mentioned in the error message this is a probable cause. To correct, change the return type to `void` or return a `string`.

Comment: And to @JohnSheridan for spotting it first.